# updating array based on symbols Ruby

Tags: ruby, symbols, ruby-2.1

How does one update the array based on symbols? Like

```
data = []
string = "Hello"
if( !data.include? string )
   count += 1
   data.insert(-1, {
       label: string,
       value: count,
   })
else
  #logic to change count value if string is encountered again
end
```

I was thinking of finding the index where the string lies and then delete that to insert another updated values at that index. Is this the right approach?

Comment: Didn't get your question properly. Are you trying to replace string with another value? user **gsub** for that.

Comment: No, the count value must be updated if I encounter another string named "Hello". So the new data array would like
    
    data = [ :label => "Hello", :value => 2 ]

Comment: Perhaps it is just me, but I do not understand what you are trying to achieve. Can you please add some example input and the expected output to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `find` to get the match, provided its the only one in the array. You can use `select` to get multiple matches. After that just update the count

As your example is taken out of context and contains errors, I've taken a liberty to make a more complete example.

```
data    = []
strings = ["Hello", "Bye", "Hello", "Hi"]

strings.each do |string|
  hash = data.find{ |h| h[:label] == string }
  if hash.nil?
    data << {label: string, value: 1}
  else 
    hash[:value] += 1
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this was it.

Comment: Yeah, I agree I should have fixed those errors.